# Weird case of a key not working

Tags: keyboard, control

I finished a game in Java. It works perfectly fine on my computer.

Sent it to a friend. On his computer, for some reason, one of the keys that are used to play doesn't work inside the game. (It works in any other context, like a web browser).

He tried pushing this key with no other keys held. Still didn't work. So it's not a 'key combination' issue.

We both use Windows and the most updated JRE version.

What could it be? This is really weird. Thanks

Comment: Please review the [help] before asking any further questions. You've had a number of off topic questions.

Answer (score 1):

I've had cases where some keys are "coded" differently based on manufacturer and appear differently in Windows. For example, I was setting up a hotkey for an application, and pressing something like [ came up as "OemSomethingSomething".

If it's an unusual key, maybe your friend's keyboard is sending a key code that Java misinterprets.